# Does writing to the HKCU registry key in Vista/Win7 require adminstrator priviliges?

Tags: windows-7, registry, uac

I have a program which writes to the HKCU registry key during startup.  Does this require administrator privileges in Vista and Win7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the answer is no, it doesn't require admin privs.  But it is possible to change the permissions on any key, so it's not a guarantee it will work.  But by default, assuming no one else is screwing around in the registry where you want to write, it should be ok.

Comment: Right, UAC won't keep you out, but regular ordinary permissions issues might.

Answer (score 2):

While OmnipotentEntity's answer is mostly correct, there are (at least) two keys in HKCU that a normal user cannot write to in the default system configuration:

- HKCU\Software\Policies
- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies